# Identification of larva on cat fur

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I found this larva (assuming it is a larva) when my cat jumped off my bed, I'm assuming she just picked it up outside. However, I'm not quite sure what it is or if it should be a concern she had it on her. When it moved, the tip of the "head" looked black and it did have "feet" like a caterpillar. If it helps, I live near middle TN and the approximate size was about an inch long. I took some pictures found below, if anyone has any information on it, thank you!

[image][image]

Comment: Made a small correction. Larvae is the Latin plural from the singular larva, which is what you are referring to.